# PHP contact form isn't working when first installed

Tags: php

I just installed a new PHP contact form but it isn't working. I already tried to fix it but I can't figure out how to fix it. Can somebody take a look at it and give me a fix? 
The PHP code:

```
      $to = 'email@hotmail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact';
      $contact_submitted = 'Your message has been sent.';


      function email_is_valid($email) {
        return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i',$email);
      }
      if (!email_is_valid($to)) {
        echo '<p style="color: red;">You must set-up a valid (to) email address before this contact page will work.</p>';
      }
      if (isset($_POST['contact_submitted'])) {
        $return = "\r";
        $youremail = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['your_email']));
        $yourname = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['your_name']));
        $yourmessage = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['your_message']));
        $contact_name = "Name: ".$yourname;
        $message_text = "Message: ".$yourmessage;
        $user_answer = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_answer']));
        $answer = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['answer']));
        $message = $contact_name . $return . $message_text;
        $headers = "From: ".$youremail;
        if (email_is_valid($youremail) && !eregi("\r",$youremail) && !eregi("\n",$youremail) && $yourname != "" && $yourmessage != "" && substr(md5($user_answer),5,10) === $answer) {
          mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
          $yourname = '';
          $youremail = '';
          $yourmessage = '';
          echo '<p style="color: blue;">'.$contact_submitted.'</p>';
        }
        else echo '<p style="color: red;">Please enter your name, a valid email address, your message and the answer to the simple maths question before sending your message.</p>';
      }
      $number_1 = rand(1, 9);
      $number_2 = rand(1, 9);
      $answer = substr(md5($number_1+$number_2),5,10);
    ?>
    <form id="contact" action="contact.php" method="post">
      <div class="form_settings">
        <p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php echo $yourname; ?>" /></p>
        <p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="<?php echo $youremail; ?>" /></p>
        <p><span>Message</span><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="5" cols="50" name="your_message"><?php echo $yourmessage; ?></textarea></p>
        <p style="line-height: 1.7em;">To help prevent spam, please enter the answer to this question:</p>
        <p><span><?php echo $number_1; ?> + <?php echo $number_2; ?> = ?</span><input type="text" name="user_answer" /><input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>" /></p>
        <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="send" /></p>
      </div>
    </form>`
```

Can somebody help me? The error I get: http://i50.tinypic.com/2hfpe7m.jpg.

Comment: How about installing it again?

Comment: "Does not work", "tried to fix it" and a link to a picture of the error message are a pretty poor problem description...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that PHP commands are showing in your page clearly indicate that PHP is either not installed, or not properly configure. Make sure that it is up and running, and that your file has a `.php` extension.

Also your source code is missing the opening `<?php`. It might only be missing from your question, but make sure it is present in your file.

Comment: That COULD also be indicative of missing braces or extra braces.

Comment: @patricksweeney You are right I added that possibility in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the opening PHP tag.

Simply add:

```
<?php
```

At the top of the script.